# Editing DMICFG utility using .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, dmi

I am trying to update system information using a batch file in DOS but when i am executing the file the information does not gets updated.

The syntax that i have been using is

DMICFG /type 01 04 "ECT "

when executing through batch file this syntax is not working but when executing directly on the command prompt then its working.

Can any one help me please??

Comment: its going is infinite loop can you please specify me??

Comment: And wht if i don want to create any other file?